# What's the equivalent of loalhost when developing on a virtual private server?

Tags: localhost, cloud, digital-ocean

This seems like a really obvious question but for some reason I couldn't find anything online that explains this. When I'm developing locally on my computer I switch back and forth between my terminal where I write my code and my browser where I view the resulting website with the localhost url and the appropriate URL.

What's the equivalent of localhost when developing on a vps like digital ocean? I don't want to use this vps as a production server, I just want to be able to preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I feel a little silly but I figured this out after reading other stuff and talking to a coworker about it.

Basically localhost is just a kind of alias for an ip address specially set aside for this purpose (127.1.1 I think). Localhost is easier to remember that a bunch of numbers but at the end of the day that's all it is. If you're working on a virtual private server like a digital ocean droplet, you just need to navigate to that ipaddress in your browser and that's your cloud equivalent of your localhost.